# Importing data on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have got a problem importing data on wordpress

> Warning:
>   Declaration of WP_Import::bump_request_timeout() should be compatible with WP_Importer::bump_request_timeout($val) in C:\xampp\htdocs\singingbowl\wp-content\plugins\wordpress-importer\wordpress-importer.php on line 38

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue the following code needs to be updated in the plugin folder:

```
Comment out the old constructor function (lines 404 to 406) in parsers.php
On Line 1110 in wordpress-importer.php replace this line: function bump_request_timeout( $val ) { with this line function bump_request_timeout( $val ) {
```

The double constructor is there because WordPress is currently providing backwards support for users that are running WordPress on servers with older versions of php.

Hope that helps anyone reading this post. If the plugin authors could make these changes when they get the chance that would be great. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Today, while trying to import demo content inside a WP theme, I've got this warning, as well as another one and even a fatal error, so the demo content import didn't complete properly.

Rather than spending time editing my theme files, I decided to temporary downgrade PHP from v7.x to v5.x, more specifically from v7.1.22 to v5.6.38 and then I was able to import the demo content without warnings or errors.

This is the solution that I would recommend.